# Visual Basic Number selector code

Tags: vb.net

Im currently developing a math game in visual basic but I need some help with a certain set of code.

I need the random numbers selected in the code: `Dim Result0 = Rnd1.Next(10, 20)`, to always end in 0 or 2 so numbers like 13 and 15 wont be selected. I need to do this because im making a division game so if a random question like 10/6 comes up I have to enter a long decimal digit which is just annoying. Here is the full code.

```
Public Class Division
    Dim Rnd1 As New Random
    Dim Rnd2 As New Random
    Dim Result0 = Rnd1.Next(10, 20)
    Dim Result1 = Rnd1.Next(1, 10)
    Dim Total = Result0 / Result1
    Dim Score As Integer = 0
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.KeyPreview = True
        TextBox1.Text = Result0
        TextBox2.Text = Result1
        Label3.Text = Total
        Label4.Text = Score

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles  Button1.Click
    Dim Rnd1 As New Random
    Dim Rnd2 As New Random
    Dim Result0 = Rnd1.Next(10, 20)
    Dim Result1 = Rnd1.Next(1, 10)
    Dim Total = Result0 / Result1

    If TextBox3.Text = Label3.Text Then
        Score += 1
        TextBox3.Text = ""
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect")
        TextBox3.Text = ""
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = Result0
    TextBox2.Text = Result1
    Label3.Text = Total
    Label4.Text = Score

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        Button1.PerformClick()
    End If


End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is test if the total is an integer before you assign all the values, and if it isn't regenerate your numbers.

Note when you divide numbers you can use "/" or "\" depending on if you want an integer value. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ex274z.aspx

```
Dim Rnd1 As New Random
Dim Rnd2 As New Random
Dim Result0 As Integer 
Dim Result1 As Integer
Dim Total As Integer

Do
    Result0 = Rnd1.Next(10, 20)
    Result1 = Rnd1.Next(1, 10)
    If Result0 / Result1 = Result0 \ Result1 Then
        Total = Result0 / Result1
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Or, you could generate your answer and the divisor and multiply them together to give you the first number :)

```
Dim Result1 = Rnd1.Next(1, 10)
Dim Total = Rnd1.Next(1, 5)
Dim Result0 = Result1 * Total
```

Comment: `you could generate your answer and the divisor and multiply them together to give you the first number` <-- my first thought. Upvoted.

Comment: i dont really understand the code very well, i tried putting it in but it doesnt work can u like help me a bit more with the placing and the indenting of the code

Comment: If you have a look at the second part of my answer and replace the three lines I've changed that might help. But if you can't actually read the code then you probably need to focus on understanding what it does before you continue on your homework.