# How to divide and get a whole number answer only in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

Im making a math game atm, in the division section i need to make sure the question the computer asks is dividable and not give 2 random numbers which will result in a decimal. ie questions like 13/5 wont come up. How do i do that. Sorry if my indentation isnt correct im new to this interface.

```
Public Class Division
Dim Rnd1 As New Random
Dim Rnd2 As New Random
Dim Result0 = Rnd1.Next(20, 40)
Dim Result1 = Rnd1.Next(1, 10)
Dim Total = Result0 / Result1
Dim Score As Integer = 0
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True
    TextBox1.Text = Result0
    TextBox2.Text = Result1
    Label3.Text = Total
    Label4.Text = Score

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Rnd1 As New Random
    Dim Rnd2 As New Random
    Dim Result0 = Rnd1.Next(20, 40)
    Dim Result1 = Rnd1.Next(1, 10)
    Dim Total = Result0 / Result1

    If TextBox3.Text = Label3.Text Then
        Score += 1
        TextBox3.Text = ""
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect")
        TextBox3.Text = ""
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = Result0
    TextBox2.Text = Result1
    Label3.Text = Total
    Label4.Text = Score

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        Button1.PerformClick()
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: This is the same as your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42615703/1070452).  And the answer doesnt change: use multiplication to get the 'answer': `a * b = c`  PIck `a` and `b` at random to get `c`; throw away `b` for them to guess

Comment: You also dont need 2 Random objects to pick 2 numbers - each one is capable of generating many, many values.  In fact creating 2 so close together (in time) *increases* the chance they will return the same value.

Comment: Use a `\ ` for integer division. For example `7 \ 5 = 1` whereas `7 / 5 = 1.4`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Basic Number selector code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615703/visual-basic-number-selector-code)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cint

Example
Dim ans as integer = cint(ans1/ans2)

Try and check it.